# Parsing JSON with section headers and section rows

Tags: php, ios, json

i am struggling with something that seems like it should be simple. Parsing the following JSON into tableview with the category name as section headers and the details within search of those sections. Here is my JSON. As you can see i have multiple categories (e.g. Baby and Other Baby Stuff, etc) and under those are details that i want under each of those categories.

```
{
"items": {
    "post": {
        "categories": [
            [
                "Baby",
                {
                    "title": "trying with category id again",
                    "price": "3344.55",
                    "category_key": "3"
                }
            ],
            [
                "Cars & Trucks",
                {
                    "title": "putting in title",
                    "price": "3000.99",
                    "category_key": "7",
                }
            ],
            [
                "Cars & Trucks",
                {
                    "title": "adding another listing",
                    "price": "400000.99",
                    "category_key": "7"
                }
            ],
```

Here is my code. Overall i have 14 categories. My code below, seems to parse the JSON and it knows there are 14 categories but the values are showing as 0, 1, 2, 3, etc (the keys) and not the actual values of category_name.

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {

//parse out the json data

NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];


_tableData = [json objectForKey:@"items"][@"post"][@"category_name"];

_filteredItemArray = [_tableData valueForKey:@"category_name"];


dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [m_tableView reloadData];

});
//_buyCategory =  json[@"items"][@"post"];
NSLog(@"Items in Dictionary: %@", _filteredItemArray); /// I CAN SEE ALL MY DATA
NSLog(@"Array Count: %u", [_filteredItemArray count]); ///THE COUNT SHOWS 14

}
```

And here is my table data stuff:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [[_filteredItemArray objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"category_name"]; ///APP CRASHES HERE...BUT THIS SEEMS RIGHT TO ME

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.

return [[[[_tableData objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:1] allKeys] count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
CustomBuyMainCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSDictionary* tempResults = [_tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

_buyTitle = [tempResults objectForKey:@"title"];
_buyPrice = [tempResults objectForKey:@"price"];

cell.buyMainTitle.text = _buyTitle;
cell.buyMainPrice.text = _buyPrice;
//NSLog(@"TempResults: %@", _buyTitle);

return cell;
}

#pragma mark - Segue
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
    BuyDetail *buyDetail = [segue destinationViewController];

    // In order to manipulate the destination view controller, another check on which table (search or normal) is displayed is needed
    if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        //buyDetail.itemDetailArray = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[m_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }
    else {

        //buyDetail.itemDetailArray = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[m_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row];
    }

}
}
```

My PHP:

```
 $channel ['json']['categories'][$category_name][]['items'][] = array(
    'ID' => $ID,
    'title' => $title,
    'price' => $price,
    'date_time' => $date_time,
    'description' => $description,

   );
}   
$channels = array($channel);
$json = json_encode($channel);
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo $json;
```

I think i am grossly missing something so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you want 'Baby' and 'Other Baby Stuff' as the title for the section header?

Comment: Yes, but i have 14 categories for now which will grow. So i don't want to specify the category name in my code. I just want to parse out the category name. does that make sense?

Comment: check my modified answer. hopefully that should suffice

Comment: In your JSON, do you happen to have a category named `"category_name"` listed under `"items":{ "post":{ "category_name": {`? If not, I can't understand how `_filteredItemArray` is not `nil` from your code.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry but what is "result"? And tempDictionary...did you mean "temp"? Its giving me error in those two places.

Comment: @Matt is right. `_filteredItemArray = [_tableData valueForKey:@"category_name"];` is incorrect

Comment: in the JSON "category_name" is meant to be the tag for each category name like Baby, Other Baby Stuff, etc.

Comment: @mreynol In the JSON posted, `category_name` is acting as a dictionary containing the category's name as the key and its contents as the value.

Comment: i updated my answer (thanks to @Matt 's observation)

Comment: Thank you again. It is giving me several errors. data is undeclared in NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&error]

Comment: @staticVoidMan In your answer, `data` should be `responseData`

Comment: @Matt : oh right. _i am not using xcode right now so_... anyways, i'll update the answer. thanks

Comment: ok, updated again. sorry. i am a mess

Comment: Okay, that fixed that error. But i still have errors in titleforHeaderinSection. filteredItemArray is now NSDictionary so i don't think objectAtIndex will work. its giving me error. Also, result is undeclared and do you mean "temp" and not "tempDictionary"?

Comment: No problem! Okay that last update fixed almost all except "result". I'm not sure what "result" is. Its undeclared.

Comment: *sigh* updated answer _for the nth time_. this is it (i guess :P)

Comment: No problem static! But shoot, keyNamesArray is declared twice. Something isn't quite right :(

Comment: oh crap shit. delete the first one since the second one is the right one

Comment: Okay. a lot closer now man. You are funny. But i'm sorry still not quite right. I changed number of sections to _tabledata which now gets me all the categories but they are out of order. It seems that is only place "table data" is used...so i'm still a little confused.

Comment: oh yeah, the `allKeys` method is a bit irritating. As per the Apple Docs on `NSDictionary`, the order is not defined. ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/allKeys so we'll use another approach. check updated answer

Comment: Okay, no problem. I also need the number of rows in each section too if you don't mind. I appreciate all your help...this is furthest i've got in days.

Comment: hm... with your JSON right now, it seems a bit problematic because within `category_name`, the key names are different. it's not erm... _normalized_. i'll post a JSON structure which, imho, is normalized and hence better

Comment: hmmm. ok. its interesting because the JSON is laid out basically how i expect the tableview to be populated. For each category, there are "items". the categories are all in order and their related items are under each category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*After the extended discussion, your JSON seems normalized and* we can proceed with the following code:

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData
{
    NSError *error;

    //declare "NSDictionary *jsonDictionary;" in the .h of this class
    //no need to make an array, simply use the response dictionary
    jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                                                     options:kNilOptions
                                                       error:&error];
   //get all keys (since there may be "holes" in the numbering)
   //declare "NSArray *arrAllKeys;" in the .h of this class
   arrAllKeys = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"] allKeys];

    [m_tableView reloadData];

    //NOTE: No need for _tableData or _filteredItemArray objects
}
```

---

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"] count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [[[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]
                              objectForKey:[arrAllKeys objectAtIndex:section]]
                              objectForKey:@"details"] count];
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]
                             objectForKey:[arrAllKeys objectAtIndex:section]]
                             objectForKey:@"categories"];
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomBuyMainCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomBuyMainCell"
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil]
                                      objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    NSString *categoryItemName = [[[[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]
                                                     objectForKey:[arrAllKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]
                                                     objectForKey:@"details"]
                                                    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                                     objectForKey:@"title"];

    NSString *categoryItemPrice = [[[[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]
                                                     objectForKey:[arrAllKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]
                                                     objectForKey:@"details"]
                                                    objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                                     objectForKey:@"price"];

    [cell.buyMainTitle setText:categoryItemName];
    [cell.buyMainPrice setText:categoryItemPrice];

    return cell;

    //NOTE: No need for tempResults or _buyTitle or _buyPrice objects anymore
    //(unless you are using _buyTitle & _buyPrice elsewhere as well)
}
```

---

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        BuyDetail *buyDetail = [segue destinationViewController];

        //declare and synthesize in the BuyDetail.h
        //"@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *selectedCategoryItem;"

        int mySelectedSection = [m_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].section;
        int mySelectedRowInSection = [m_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;

        buyDetail.selectedCategoryItem = [[[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]
                                                            objectAtIndex:[arrAllKeys objectAtIndex:mySelectedSection]]
                                                            objectForKey:@"details"]
                                                           objectAtIndex:mySelectedRowInSection];

        //NOTE: selectedCategoryItem is a dictionary object in your BuyDetail
        //handle it like as you would handle any other dictionary
    }
}
```

---

The `distance` values are in integer so we need to do fetch it this way:

```
int distanceInMiles = [[[[[[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]
                                            objectForKey:[arrAllKeys objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]]
                                            objectForKey:@"details"]
                                           objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                            objectForKey:@"distance"]
                                            objectForKey:@"miles"] intValue];

//assuming categoryItemDistance is NSString object
categoryItemDistance = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",distanceInMiles];
```

Comment: oh so close! I'm just getting error here: no visible at @interface for NSArray:     if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomBuyMainCell"
                                              owner:self
                                            options:nil]
                                  objectAtIndexPath:0];

Comment: @mreynol : oh shats again... it should be `cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomBuyMainCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];` ...it's not `objectAtIndexPath:0` it should be `objectAtIndex:0`. reason: `NSArray` does not provide any instance method called `-objectAtIndexPath:`. it provides `objectAtIndex:`. it's just one of my several typo :/ . my bad, i'll update my answer ...

Comment: ok that cleared the error! But when i'm running now its crashing :(

Comment: -[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14597b60
2013-11-29 09:40:42.999 OnTradar[20438:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14597b60'

Comment: @mreynol : ohhhhhhh... inside `items`, you have "1" as the name of a key and then it's value is the rest. similarly, you have a key by the name "2" and it's respective value and so on and so forth. hm... it looked exactly like an array... but... is not. no probs. lets see

Comment: seems to be here: return [[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]

Comment: YEEEEEEEEEEHAAAAAAAWWWWWWWWWWW!!!!!!! WOOOOOHOOOOO!!!!!!! IT WORKED...in case you couldn't tell!!! DUDE...you are THE MAN!!!!

Comment: man, you have really gone above and beyond! if you private messaged me your address...i will send you beer...or something! you have no idea how much i appreciate your help!

Comment: @mreynol : it's my pleasure. i like to help and i'm glad that your issue has been solved. Well... it was mostly the JSON that needed to be structured properly :)

Comment: Okay, so i hate to ask but would appreciate one last thing...on the prepare for segue. It used to pass my table data array to an itemtabledata array for the item details. buyDetail.itemDetailArray = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:[m_tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row].

Comment: @mreynol : you could have optimized your JSON one more step if you had made the value of your `items` node an array instead of a dictionary (_what it is now, you know... the "1" and the "2" and the "3"_ ... it also seems your logic doesn't fill the last node correctly i.e. "15"... must be the loop in your PHP script)

Comment: @mreynol : you mean the `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: well, i  had a different function. i updated my question with this part.

Comment: @mreynol : actually, better yet, tell me what you expect to show in `BuyDetail`

Comment: well ok so in my JSON, i'm gonna show...title, price, description, distance, etc...pretty much most of what is in details for each item.

Comment: @mreynol : hmm... this is gonna change your `BuyDetail` a bit but let me see how to keep it as close to your current implementation

Comment: @mreynol : updated answer (_there was no point adhering to the previous flow_). Now... we simply set a dictionary object of class `BuyDetails` with the currently selected item's `details` values... which is everything related to that item. make the necessary modification to `BuyDetails` class (_i.e. the way you populate data in `BuyDetails` view. it should be dictionary specific retrieval now_)

Comment: Wouldn't it be like this on my detail view? _buyTitle.text = [_selectedCategoryItem objectForKey:@"title"];

Comment: @mreynol : yes, it should

Comment: it seems its not getting passed to selectedCategoryItem. I'm running an NSLog and its showing NULL

Comment: @mreynol : updated answer -- in `-prepareForSegue:` method, have removed `if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)` condition.

Comment: That did it! I was like...what the heck is going on! Thank you! By the way, do you contract your time instead of me mooching off you...in case i need further assistance with anything?

Comment: @mreynol : aah, i was wondering why you had the `searchDisplayController` condition in the previous code (_didnt wanna break any dependency_) but now it should be smooth sailing for awhile :) also, i do contract work although not recently but it's ok. you can catch me here quite often (i like to check up on _solvable_ problems. it quickens my learning curve)

Comment: I appreciate your help! Okay last question for the day..i promise. in my details some data for "Distance" and then "Miles". I'm trying to get at Miles like title and price:         categoryItemDistance = [[[[[[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"items"]
                                    objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.section+1]]
                                   objectForKey:@"details"]
                                  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
                                 objectForKey:@"distance"]
                                objectForKey:@"miles"];

Comment: @mreynol : updated answer (_the `miles` and `kilometers` are not `string` objects, they're `integer` so you'll have to use `intValue` method to get them_)

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!!! Okay, i will leave you alone now! This has been great help to me and also learning opportunity. :)

Comment: @mreynol : haha. my pleasure. _see ya around here again... sometime..._

Comment: Hey Static! If you have your ears on and are bored...would you have a look at my new question? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508297/ios-posting-images-and-data-to-php-mysql-database

Comment: @mreynol : sorry, am a bit busy this week. i'll have a look though.

Comment: @mreynol : nope, that's not really my strong suit right now but i'll check

Comment: static...i hate to bother you but it seems we have a little bug with the above code here. If the JSON has an item in a category and the category before it does NOT have an item, then that item will not display in my app. Any idea how we can adjust the code above to fix that?

Comment: @mreynol : no issues, i like something to do :) ...kindly post a snippet of your json that displays a normal case as well as the mentioned _buggy_ scenario

Comment: thanks man! Well, the json is accurate...it ALWAYS shows the items correctly. Its just the parsing with the above code that doesn't want to parse if we don't have an item in the very first category. Do you still need the json?

Comment: @mreynol : yes, a snippet of the json would be great

Comment: Wait a sec! Maaaaybe it is my JSON! Please stand by while i confirm. :) Sorry...of course now i see something different. :)

Comment: @mreynol : ok, so it's all good, right? great... so anyways, visit http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45135/hitme , you can drop a message there when needed

Comment: i THINK it is...but i will let you know in that chat. Thank you again so much for responding! :)

Comment: Okay i posted into the chat room :)