# iOS Posting images and data to PHP mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, ios, uiimage

I am attempting to POST several pictures along with text data to my PHP page and then into mySQL database but I am getting a 400 error response and i am unable to post anything.

I am able to POST only data or only pictures, but not both together.
It seems I am not setting up the POST correctly.

*I need to post many pictures but was just trying to get one rolling for now*.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image1.image, 10);
//Add boundary
NSMutableString *boundary = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"----Boundary+"];

//Append 5 random chars to the end of the boundary
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    BOOL lowercase = arc4random() % 2;

    if(lowercase){
        [boundary appendFormat:@"%c", (arc4random() % 26) + 97];
    }
    else {
        [boundary appendFormat:@"%c", (arc4random() % 26) + 65];
    }

    //Commit to mySQL Database
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title=%@&price=%@&description=%@&latitude=%@&longitude=%@&location=%@&category_id=%@",sellTitle, sellPrice, sellDescription, sellLatitude, sellLongitude, sellLocation, sellCategory];

    NSLog(@"PostData: %@",post);

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myURL/testphp.php"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    //PICTURE STUFF
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"picture.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Setting the body of the post to the request
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;

    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Response code:%d", [response statusCode]);

    if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300) {
        NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Respinse ==> %@", responseData);

        //Now lets make the connection to the web
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
        NSLog(@"%@",boundary);
        NSLog(@"Title Saved: %@", sellTitle);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code i managed to get working for this. This is working perfectly.

```
   //begin new method

    NSString *urlString = @"http://www.yourURLforPostingData.com";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    // picture
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(_image1.image, .25);

    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"picture.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:imageData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Description Text
    NSString *description = [defaults objectForKey:@"description"];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"description\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:description] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Title Text
    NSString *title = [defaults objectForKey:@"sellTitle"];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"title\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:title] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    //return and test
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);


 //END NEW METHOD
```

Comment: so... what was the issue. kindly mention that in your answer. maybe someone can benefit from it (_plus good reading material for me_)